# How to transparent remove image shadow

Tags: html, css, image

I have a html code with css

```
<style>
        #lightbox {
            position:fixed; /* keeps the lightbox window in the current viewport */
            top:0; 
            left:0; 
            width:100%; 
            height:100%; 
            background:url(overlay.png) repeat; 
            text-align:center;
        }
        #lightbox p {
            text-align:right; 
            color:#fff; 
            margin-right:20px; 
            font-size:12px; 
        }
        #lightbox img {
            box-shadow:0 0 25px #111;
            -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 25px #111;
            -moz-box-shadow:0 0 25px #111;
            max-width:940px;
        }
        </style>
```

and in my html I have a .png logo image which is transparent the logo image is showing showed to it, and I want to remove that showed. 
Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: which shadow? the little border-shadow or the big gray all around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove these lines from your css:

```
#lightbox img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgb(17, 17, 17);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgb(17, 17, 17);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 25px #111;
}
```

Or add these lines after that

```
#lightbox img {
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: removing lines worked thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove these properties on the `#lightbox` `img`

```
#lightbox img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px #111;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px #111;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 25px #111;
}
```

Comment: lol, you removed a different shadow than me, which one does he want to remove i wonder... OP doesnt really specify

Comment: @watson Didn't even realize what CSS I pasted in :p

Comment: I want a transparent background, it will remove this background

Comment: +1 yes, thank you, @watson also has the same answer

Comment: @PankajKhairnar I pasted in the wrong CSS.. and just so you know, people are voting to close your question. Change it to include relevant CSS/HTML

Comment: yes I'll add some more description to it. thank you